got the same XmlException no matter what the content of the HTML is
I am currently using the Adobe SDK to convert HTML to PDF. However, I am encountering an error regardless of the HTML file I upload, even with the simplest HTML containing only "hello world." The error message I receive is System.Xml.XmlException: The 'meta' start tag on line 7 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 344, position 3. I’ve shared the same code with my colleague, and it works fine on his laptop. I suspect it might be an issue with Visual Studio. My version is Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022, 17.8.1. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?
